# How to create a generic array with multiple models in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am trying to create a generic array with different models. I have a parser method like that. But it doesn't work because it returns `[Any]` and it's not typesafe. I need to access my Movie and CastMember objects after parse method. I will use this array in my tableviewcontroller delegate methods. How can I do that?

```
static func parseSearchResult(_ data:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> [Any] {

    var array = [Any]()
    let jsonData = JSON(data)
    if let resultData = jsonData["results"].arrayObject {
        let result = resultData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
        for element in result {

            if((element["media_type"]?.isEqual("person"))!){
                let person = CastMember(json: element)
                array.append(person)
            }
            else if((element["media_type"]?.isEqual("movie"))!){
                let movie = Movie(json: element)
                array.append(movie)
            }
        }
    }
    return array
}
```

and these are my structs

```
struct CastMember{
    var id : Int?
    var originalName : String?
    var castName : String?
    var picturePath : String?
    
    init(json: [String:Any]){
        originalName = json["name"] as? String
        id = json["id"] as? Int
        castName = json["character"] as? String
        picturePath = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/"
        picturePath?.append((json["profile_path"] as? String) ?? "")
    }
}

struct Movie{
    var id : Int?
    var title : String?
    var imagePath : String?
    
    init(json: [String:Any]){
        title = json["title"] as? String
        id = json["id"] as? Int
        imagePath = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/"
        imagePath?.append((json["poster_path"] as? String)!)
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try to create a `MediaType` protocol that `Movie` and `CastMember` conform to, and then your function would return `[MediaType]` instead of `[Any]`.

Comment: yesimvs: please share your model structs/classes.

Comment: You should really look into adapting the `Codable` protocol to easily extract your data from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Movie and CastMember classes confirm to the protocol Codable.

also you will have to write a struct or class which matches the response data , like it must have an array of results and any other key coming in response.

```
struct ResponseModel<T> : Codable {
   let results : [T]
}
```

then decode it like this :

```
let response : ResponseModel = JSONDecoder.decode(T.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a `protocol`

Example:

```
enum MediaType {
  case movie, castMember 
}

protocol SearchResult {
  var title: String { get }
  var mediaType: MediaType { get }
}

struct SearchResultViewModel: SearchResult {

   let title: String
   let mediaType: MediaType

   init(title: String, mediaType: MediaType) {
     self.title = title
     self.mediaType = mediaType
   }
}
```

Then your `parseSearchResult` should return an array of `[SearchResult]` objects that conforms to the protocol, in this case, an array of `SearchResultViewModel`